# x86 - dma_alloc_coherent and contiguous pages

Tags: memory-management, x86, dma

#### The context:

This morning, I had a lecture about virtual memory and dma.
Everything was explained very fast and the teacher left the room immediately at the end, telling me he would answer my question next time. *"OK. I don't want to understand tomorrow"*.

#### So, the question is:

on X86 and for a kernel module, for a given pcie device able to address a 32-bit range, **will `dma_alloc_coherent()` always be trying to get memory in the free kernel space (usually the top 1Gb)?**

Since the memory is mapped there and the kernel always sits on physically contiguous pages, two contiguous virtual pages should be physically contiguous there as well, yes? (to allocate, say 16K memory, I would search 4 free contiguous virtual pages, and I need not use `remap_pfn_range` since it is in kernel space only).

Comment: Look at the source code. Maybe you find something valuable there.

Comment: I did already and this is the conclusion I came with. But am I wrong?

Comment: @cad: do you think I am correct? Reading the freebsd implementation, we talk about kernel memory arena. Same thing in the end.